# When creating superuser on heroku I receive the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I already installed djangorestframework both using python and python3. This error only appears when using

heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser

I have also tried heroku run python3 manage.py createsuperuser

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'core',
]
```

Comment: did you add `djangorestframework` to your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Yes I did (djangorestframework==3.11.1) and also to my Pipfile

Comment: "and also to my Pipfile"—don't use a `requirements.txt` _and_ a `Pipfile`. Choose one or the other. Are you installing things with the `pip` or `pipenv` command locally?

Comment: Ok it worked when I removed the Pipfile and only used requirements.txt. Thank you!